# How to copy and delete files using a bat file with arguements

Tags: windows, batch-file, scheduled-tasks, xcopy

I want to copy files across computers on the network using a bat file (I want to run the bat file in windows scheduler) but only have files copied based on their last modified dates, e.g. only copy files across to another computer only if the last modified date is older than 3 months then when the coping is done have the copied files delete on the source computer.

Answer (score 1):

Robocopy (included in Windows 7+, downloadable for older versions from Microsoft's site) has options that do exactly what you need.

Robocopy /mov /minage:90 [src] [dest]

would seem to be close to what you need.